# Is it possible to define screen reader, reading order on native apps?

Tags: android, ios, accessibility

For a screen to be read out in a logical and sequential order, a reading order, for native apps, could be useful, to ensure that elements are read out, in an expected order.

How is reading order determined by native apps, in relation to screen readers?

Websites can define tab index order, and the order is determined by the order of the DOM.

Is this true of native apps? Is there any native app equivalent of tab index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general, native apps essentially follow a "DOM" order but you can change that order with [`accessibilityElements`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615147-accessibilityelements) for iOS. It's just an array and will be read in order.

For Android, you'd use [`nextFocusUp`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:nextFocusUp) (or Down, Left, or Right). There are a few other "nextFocus..." attributes.